# How can I create a "duck-typed" grpc protobuf Message at runtime in Go?

Tags: json, go, protocol-buffers, grpc, duck-typing

I'm using grpc protobuf Message definitions and implementing them in Go.

My ultimate goal is for my rpc to retrieve some json on a user and return a `Profile` Message with optional, nested Messages to be used for unmarshalling a subset of the json.

using this rpc:

```
  rpc GetUser (GetUserRequest) returns (Profile) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/user/{id=*}"
    };
  }
```

and assuming the following json:

```
{
  "profile": {
     "foo": {
        "name": "tim"
        "age": 22
      },
     "bar": {
       "level": 5
     }
  }
}
```

I want to return a `Profile` Message containing  only "foo", "bar", or both, as nested Messages based on an incoming runtime `scope` parameter of the grpc request (currently, `scope` would be a list of strings containing the Message names to be used for subsetting the json into respective Messages e.g. `["Foo","Bar"]`).

given these Message definitions:

```
message Profile {
  //both Foo & Bar are optional by default
  Foo foo = 1 [json_name="foo"];
  Bar bar = 2 [json_name="bar"];
}

message Foo {
  string name = 1 [json_name="name"];
  int32 age = 2 [json_name="age"];
}

message Bar {
  string level = 1 [json_name="level"];
}
```

then in the case that `scope` is `["Foo"]`, I'd like the rpc to return:

```
Profile{
  Foo: // Foo Message unmarshalled from json
}
```

or if `"scope"` is `["Foo","Bar"]` then:

```
Profile{
  Foo: 
  Bar:
}
```

The problem seems to boil down to "duck-typing" a Message type.

## Attempt 1

I got close to finding a solution using `protoreflect` & `protoregistry` by doing:

```
import(
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoregistry"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect"
)

var scope protoreflect.FullName = "Foo"
var types = new(protoregistry.Types)
var message, errs = types.FindMessageByName(scope)
var almost_foo = message.New()

// using `myJson` object without top level "profile" key to make testing more simple at the moment
var myJson = `{ "foo": { .. }, "bar", { ... } }`
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(myJson), almost_foo)
```

but when I attempt to create Profile Message using `almost_foo`:

```
var profile = &pb.Profile{almost_foo}
```

I get error: `cannot use almost_foo (type protoreflect.Message) as type *package_name.Foo in field value`

## Attempt 2

using

```
import(
  "github.com/jhump/protoreflect/desc"
  "github.com/jhump/protoreflect/dynamic"
)
```

I try to dynamically create the message again:

```
var fd, errs = desc.LoadFileDescriptor("github.com/package/path/..")
var message_desc = fd.FindMessage("Foo")
var almost_foo = dynamic.NewMessage(message_desc)
```

and a similar error occurs:
`cannot use almost_foo (type *dynamic.Message) as type *package_name.Foo in field value`

Both attempts almost create a Message but the type system still doesn't allow either to actually be used.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by whittling down the json to what I want first and then putting it through Unmarshal.

I created a top level Message that takes `Profile` as a field:

```
message GetUserResponse {
  Profile profile = 1;
}
```

and redefined the response:

```
rpc GetUser (GetUserRequest) returns (GetUserResponse)
```

To build the allowed/scoped json, I use:

```
"github.com/tidwall/gjson"
"github.com/tidwall/sjson"
```

I copy the json dictated by the scope paths (dot-delimited e.g. `["profile.foo"]`) over to an initially empty, output, `response_json` string, and build up only the allowed json to be returned.

```
var response_json string

var scopes = []string{"profile.foo"}

for _, scope := range scopes {
    // copy allowed json subset in raw form
    value := gjson.Get(myJson, scope + "|@ugly")

    // if scope didn't copy a value, skip
    if value.String() == "" {
        continue
    } else {
        // write value to output json using SetRaw since value can be an object
        response_json, _ = sjson.SetRaw(response_json, scope, value.Raw)
    }
}
```

response_json looks like:

```
{
  "profile": {
     "foo": {
        "name": "tim"
        "age": 22
      }
  }
}
```

and then Unmarshal:

```
response = &pb.VerifyUserResponse{}
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(response_json), response)
```